# Quote ticker in C#

Tags: c#

I want to make a Quote Ticker Control  in C#
in which Live data should be come from stock exchange
How i will do it

Thanks

Comment: Has anyboody noticed the influx of "Give me teh codez or else!" questions this morning?

Comment: This morning? For months and months it's been on the increase. But don't dare suggest that the answer to a question such as this should be "Write some code to retrieve live quote data and present it in a ticker control." which is in all reasonable ways a valid answer to this question, however sarcastic.

Comment: What is it with some peoples' obsession with stock quotes...

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen - It's a warren buffet obsession..if he can do it I can! :)

Comment: @Matti - Cuz dats howz dey make teh moneyz? (Sorry, my LoLCat is a little lacking...but that's really all questions like this deserve).

Comment: @JonH: ...who? @Justin: Really? Just staring at stock quotes scroll by makes you money? Hold on, I've got some software to write...

Comment: The same way as you solve any problem in development: break the problem down into smaller pieces that are more manageable.  Think about how those small pieces will interact, and design them in a way that makes the interaction easy.  Then, when you have a specific problem with a specific portion of your application, come back and ask on StackOverflow - where the community is happy to help you do the trickier parts of your job, but won't blindly do it for you.

Answer (score 10):

Read up on web services, it will probably be the best way to get upto date live information and then you'd use the results to update your control on your C# form.

[This article should help you out!](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Build-a-C-sharp-Stock-Quote-WebService-Part-1/)

Try to work out some of it and post specific questions.

Answer (score 5):

1. Plan
2. Implement
3. Test
4. Deploy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for a web application, in addition to web services you will probably want to look into AJAX so you can refresh the data without having to postback the page.