# Quote Ticker in C#

Tags: c#

How To make a Quote Ticker in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quote ticker in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397303/quote-ticker-in-c)

Comment: You need to be more descriptive.

Comment: you asked this question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397303/quote-ticker-in-c-closed

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, simply:

1. Learn C#
2. Make a quote ticker

In all seriousness, you really need to give us more to go on. Where in particular are you stuck for example?

Comment: Hi I have successed to make it How i can Post My code plz tell me